# Keycloak Account Console list clients

Tags: java, keycloak

There is a list of client application in the Account Console => Applications. One is a Spring Boot web application:
[image]

another one is the Account Console itself:
[image]

Is it possible to make the "prosto-client" clicable so that the user could be redirected from his Account Console to `http://localhost:8082/` which is the Valid Redirect URI of the client?

I have created a realm "test", in that realm created a user and set a password to the user. Also I have created a client "prosto-client" in the realm with the following settings:

> Client Protocol: openid-connect
> Access type: Confidential
> Standard flow enabled: On
> Direct access grants enabled: On
> Valid redirects URI: `http://localhost:8082/*`

Then I have created a Spring Boot application and configured it as a Keycloak client for the realm "test". When the user makes a request to `http://localhost:8082`, he is redirected to Keycloak authorization url `http://localhost:9990/auth/` and after successful authentication the user is redirected back to `http://localhost:8082`. Everything works fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the field "Base URL" in the client configuration in KeyCloak - this determines the link from the Applications List. You can use an absolute URL with protocol and host there. But as you could configure multiple valid redirect URIs it's probably not possible to make this configuration dependent on that field.